# Form input field only allowing the letter '8' in IE9

Tags: html, forms, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, textinput

I have a Rails site and a web form that works fine in IE7 and IE8. But in IE9, one of the input text fields only allows the digit '8' with IE9.0.8112. I would appreciate any ideas. Thanks.

The code is [here (Line 410)](https://gist.github.com/1218707).

Comment: looks like something related to your validation script, if you remove that script does it work fine?

Comment: Parvesh, I remove a validation javascript and that did the trick. If you add that as an answer, I can give you credit.